# Visual Studio default Blazor server side web application counter button works in IIS browse but not over the internet

Tags: windows, iis, blazor-server-side, portforwarding

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (as Administrator) and IIS Express with the extra Widows 10 features needed to publish web sites on the internet. I created a new Blazor app with the following choices:

- Server Side
- .NET 5.0 (because .net3.1 does not have ProtectedBrowserStorage)
- Authentication - None
- Configure for HTTPS (because my domain name uses Cloudflare servers)
- Enable Docker - No
- Environmental variables

  - Project properties - None
  - Windows AdvancedSystemSettings - Development
    I did not add any more components nor did I modify the default code.
    I built and ran it in release mode.
    The web site displayed the home page on a Chrome browser.
    I could navigate to the Counter page.
    When I clicked the "Click Me" button the current count incremented as it should.

Then I published it to the default file ("~bin\release\net5.0\publish).
I copied this file (with admin privileges) into inetpub and renamed it "B02".

In IIS I created a new web site  called B02 specifying the physical path as C:\inetpub\B02.
New App Pool B02 was created and I accepted it.
I did not add a specific user so Test Connection failed but I think this is OK.
I added two bindings

- https  port 443 IP Address *
- https  port 443 IP Address 19.168.0.34 (the reserved address of the computer on the router to which port 443 is forwarded. i.e. I'm using port forwarding on a NetGear router)

I could then click, in IIS, "Browse*:443(https) and the web site was OK. I could navigate to any page and all links worked including the "Click Me" button which incremented the counter.

The problem is that when I enter into the Chrome browser the address
"https://www.bkdaniels.com" the web site appears, I can navigate to any of the three pages, the About button works, the "Brief Survey" button works BUT THE "CLICK ME" BUTTON DOES NOT INCREMENT THE COUNT. (It does change the style of the border of the button).

I have presented this simple problem in the hopes that it will enable me to make user interactions work on a custom web app I have written. Presently they all work in IIS browse but not over the internet.

My domain name "bkdaniels.com" is registered with GoDaddy where I have specified to use name servers at Cloudflare because Cloudflare provides and SSL Certificate that prevents clients seeing a warning about the site being not secure.

7/29/22 A solution has been found.
A couple of trivial changes that cleaned up warnings in the Browser console were as follows:

- Installed 6.0 SDK
- Added to Program.cs - app.UseWebSockets()

These alone did not solve the problem. the Counter click me button still failed to increment the count.

The action that solved the problem was to go to GoDaddy and change the nameservers from Cloudflare servers to GoDaddy default name servers.

I then had to by pass the security warning since I no longer had the SSL certificate that Cloudflare provided. So I clicked "Run Anyway".

The "click me" button incremented the counter.

I will now work with Cloudflare support to find a way to make it work through their nameservers.

8/15/2022 I have now found that a temporary workaround is to set the Cloudflare Dashboard Cache to Developer Mode. This solves the problem with the counter button and also enables my main web site to work. I am still looking for a proper solution.

---

8/29/2022 **SOLUTION**

*This solution enabled the click on the default Blazor Server app to work and it also enabled my serious web site to work perfectly.*

Cloudflare/ logon/ domain name/ dashboard/ speed/ optimization/ auto minify/ HTML / **OFF**

---

.

Comment: .NET 5 is end of life, and .NET 6 introduced many changes (and bug fixes) in this field, so if you don't upgrade to .NET 6 this discussion isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: Thanks. VS 2019 does not work with .NET 6 so I have purchased VS 2022 and plan to test again with it and .NET 6.

Comment: I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 and using .NET 6 I still have the same problem. A trivial change was to put the physical folder into C:\Published Web Apps. I found it necessary to install the .NET 6 Core Hosting Bundle. Also, I noticed that before I click the Counter button there is a warning in the f12 Console window that it failed to connect via Web Sockets and fell back to long polling. I am starting to investigate this. Now. Please note that this is an OUT OF THE BOX APP so it should work.